# $M$ noetherian module over noetherian ring $A$, $I\subset A$ ideal. Then $\exists 0\neq m\in M, Im=0$ iff $\forall x\in I,\exists 0\neq m\in M,xm=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

$M$ noetherian module over noetherian ring $A$, $I\subset A$ ideal. Then $\exists 0\neq m\in M, Im=0$ iff $\forall x\in I,\exists 0\neq m\in M,xm=0$

Forward implication is obvious. I am kind of having trouble to prove this directly without using associated primes here. It amounts to prove the converse statement by inducting on the number of generators of $I$. It suffices to prove the basic case for 2 generated $I$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Here is my thought process. Suppose $I=(f_1,f_2)$. By assumption, there is $m_1,m_2\in M-0$ s.t. $f_im_i=0$. $f_1m_1=0$ is good. It suffices to consider $J=(m_2:_Am_1)$ quotient ideal. WLOG, $m_2\not\in (m_1)$. Thus $J\neq A$. However, I could not see $J\neq 0$. Furthermore, there is no guarantee that $Jm_2\neq 0$. Hint or suggestion on how to proceed?

Ref. Serre Local Algebra pg 8, Prop 7.

Comment: Can you give a proof using associated primes here?Thank you.

Comment: @Sky Associated primes proof is not too hard here. First condition clearly implies $I\subset\cup_{p\in Ass(M)}p$. Prime avoidance gives $I\subset p$ for some $p\in Ass(M)$. Second condition is saying those $x$ considered as $I\subset\cup_{x\in I}(x)\subset\cup_{p\in Ass(M)}p$. Apply prime avoidance again. The equivalence of $I\subset p\in Ass(M)$ iff $I\subset\cup_{p\in Ass(M)}p$ is obvious by prime avoidance. Then the statement follows.

Comment: I do not have an answer to your question. In your post, a couple of places needs to be checked. The notation of the colon makes sense if the first component is a module, i.e., $Am_2$, and $J \neq 0$ since $f_1 \in J$. I thought your goal was to find a suitable $m \in M$ for the given ideal $I$. Why considering such $J$ is sufficient?

Comment: @Youngsu Well, normally you want to recombine $m_1,m_2$ into a new element. That is why I want to consider quotient ideal to try to write an element $m_2$ in terms of other combinations of $m_1$ s.t. $m'_2$ is annhilated by $f_1$. Then I can try to pick a modified $m$ from $(m_1)\subset (m_1,m_2)$ filtration. That is what I expect but I do not think this will hold as associated prime gives something more than this. It gives $m\in M$ s.t. $I\subset Ann(m)\in Spec(A)$. If there is alternative way to show this directly, I would like to try without associated primes.